# Parsing json into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
{
  "type_a": {
    "2015-08-07": {
      "is_available": false, 
      "variable": 0.282
    }, 
    "2015-08-23": {
      "is_available": false, 
      "variable": 0.296
    },
    "2017-03-28": {
      "is_available": false, 
      "variable": 0.524
    }
  }, 
  "type_b": {
    "2015-06-27": {
      "is_available": true, 
      "variable": 0.038
    }, 
    "2015-07-30": {
      "is_available": true, 
      "variable": 0.035
    },
    "2017-04-27": {
      "is_available": true, 
      "variable": 0.158
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to load the above json into a pandas dataframe and make both `is_available` and `variable` column names, so eventual structure looks like so:

```
             data_source      is_available     variable
2015-08-07     type_a            false           0.282
2015-08-23     type_a            false           0.296
2017-03-28     type_a            false           0.524
2015-06-27     type_b            true            0.038  
2015-07-30     type_b            true            0.035
2015-04-27     type_b            true            0.158
```

currently, I do this:

```
pd.read_json(json)
```

Comment: Does it not break on the use of true and false? Because that's not python syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I assume your data is called `data`, this will do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i, j): data[i][j] for i in data.keys() for j in data[i].keys()}, orient='index')
df['data_source'] = df.index.droplevel(level=1)
df.index = df.index.droplevel(level=0)
```